# How to ClickLink through WicketTester when links have the same wicket:id?

Tags: java, html, junit, wicket

On a Wicket page, I produce links with images via the following:

```
@Override
protected void populateItem(ListItem<Club> item) 
{
    ...
    Image joinButton = new Image("joinButton", joinResource);
    BookmarkablePageLink<PageClubJoin> joinLink = 
        new BookmarkablePageLink<PageClubJoin>("joinLink", PageClubJoin.class);
    joinLink.setParameter("club", item.getModelObject().getId());
    joinLink.add(joinButton);
    item.add(joinLink);
    ...
```

The rendered html produces a series of

```
<a wicket:id="joinLink" ... />
```

elements.

Now, how do I use WicketTester to ClickLink on, say, the second one? They all have the same wicket:id.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You provide the full path to the component separated by colons:

```
tester.clickLink("listView:0:joinLink");
```

The first part is the list view component ID, the second the number of the item you want to select and the third part the link that you want to click. So if you want to click the link in the 99nth item in the list you would use:

```
tester.clickLink("listView:99:joinLink");
```

Comment: Good, except I asked for the second link, so answer strictly speaking is listView:1:joinLink

Comment: You were right, I was a bit concise. I improved the solution with more explanation for future readers.

Comment: Just in case you're wondering about how to access a certain element on your page [Component.getPageRelativePath()](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#getPageRelativePath()) and [BaseTester.debugComponentTrees()](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/util/tester/BaseWicketTester.html#debugComponentTrees%28%29) are two very helpful friends...